# Unable to upload file to S3 using AWS SDK running on MAC OS El Capitan

Tags: java, macos, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

When I try to upload a file using the AWS SDK in java on my MAC OS, I am unable to get a "upload complete" message. No errors are thrown. The program never terminates. This seems to happen only on a Mac as others in my company ran the exact same code on a Windows and Linux Ubuntu and did not encounter this issue. specs below.

Hardware: MAC OS El Capitan 10.11.4

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)

Firewall is currently off.

Note: I am able to manually upload to S3 without any issues.[image]

Comment: If you had posted code instead of a picture maube I could have helped

Comment: Pasting the code would not have helped as you can see from the solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution. the answer is to update the java version on the Mac to Java 8 160 and above. any older version will not work due to some policy issue.